# Rails Routing current_page issue in Application Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, navbar, current-page

I feel like this should be simple but for some reason I can't figure this out. I just want to add the edit and delete actions to the navbar when a user is on the show page.

I'm getting a route error saying the edit action doesn't exist on the homepage or the new page, here's my code:

```
layouts/application.html.haml

.nav-collapse
   %ul.nav.pull-right
      %li= link_to "All Articles", root_path
      %li= link_to "New Article", new_article_path
      - if current_page?(@article)
        %li= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path
        %li= link_to 'Delete', { :action => :destroy, :id => @article.id }, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?'
```

Answer (score 0):

The link to `edit` page should have an `id` (or something relative) of the object you want to edit. So, the link helper should be written:

`link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) # or explicitly (@article.id)`